# Filterregisteration Bean and injection of a collection @Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, el

We have a configuration class:

```
public class FilterConfigBase {

   @Bean
   public FilterRegisterationBean 
   corsFilter(@value("${client.ip.headers:}") List<String> 
   clientIpHeaders) 
   {
    ....
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Application.properties:

```
client.ip.headers=A,B,C
```

We have a `DefaultConversion` service bean (which has `StringToCollectionConverter`)

In `FilterConfigBase` (Which contains only `FIlterRegisterationBean`), `@Value` annotation is not calling the `StringToCollectionConverter` class instead the conversion result is:

```
clientIpHeaders[0]="A,B,C"
```

Whereas in other configuration classes, `@Value` annotation is able to resolve the property, It calls the `StringToCollectionConverter` and the values are properly populated.

```
clientIpHeaders.get(0)="A"
clientIpHeaders.get(1)="B"
clientIpHeaders.get(2)="C"
```

For more details:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11585

Comment: If we need to convert application property to a collection, DefaultConversionService is the recommended class. Spring will automatically detect the conversionService and use it.

We have a FilterConfig class (Java based configuration), which contains only FilterRegisterationBean declaration. In that class alone the @Value(("${client.ip.headers:}" List<String> clientIpHeaders)) is not working. 
It is not using the defaultConversionService.
Rather splitting it, it populates the entire string as the first element of the list.
It happens only during bean creation during filterRegisteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a bit of EL there to split into list:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegisterationBean 
corsFilter(@value("#{'${client.ip.headers:}'.split(',')}") List<String> 
clientIpHeaders)
```

Comment: Already tried Spring EL, it works. But want to know why springboot is not using DefaultConversionService in this case.

Comment: I don't think there is any BeanPostProcessor for FIlterRegisterationBean.